# NPM Install failing after macOs Update to Monterey

Tags: node.js, sass, gruntjs

Im not sure how to fix this error on Node.
I get below error when I run npm install to setup Grunt Sass in the server.
I have upgraded to latest Mac OS - Monterrey yesterday.

```
npm ERR! code E404
    npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://codeload.github.com/ariya/esprima/legacy.tar.gz/master
    npm ERR! 404 
    npm ERR! 404  'esprima@https://github.com/ariya/esprima/tarball/master' is not in this registry.
    npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
    npm ERR! 404 
    npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
    npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/dev/.npm/_logs/2021-11-04T06_28_26_067Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Whatever project you're trying to install is using a way-old `esprima`. You'll probably need to upgrade some dependencies before you can get going.